# Why gameloops render more times than updating

Tags: java, java-2d, game-development, game-loop

Many game loops use tick and render, when tick is done every X ms and render whenever possible. Why not ticking then rendering?
The way I see it, between ticks the render will draw the same thing, so why call it more than once? (if not explain why please)

the typical gameloop is:

```java
public void run() {

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double nsBetweenTicks = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsBetweenTicks;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >=1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            render();
       }
}
```

My question is why not:

```java
public void run() {

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double nsBetweenTicks = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsBetweenTicks;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >=1){
                tick();
                render();
                delta--;
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: The while loop is there to let the ticks catch up with the elapsed time. This way the objects move at a realistic pace, even if, for whatever reason, the UI wasn't able to render for every tick. Since it is trying to catch up here because the entire loop including rendering was too slow, you will likely never catch up if you render every time in the catch-up loop.

Comment: @Erwin That a good point, but isn't it a bad thing if the game updates multiple times and only then the image changes (drastic change from previous image)? Maybe I should just lower the fps if I cant tick and render at the same time. Also, most of the time, I can render 150-200 times when ticking 60 per second. Even in this case I shouldn't tick and render together?

Comment: I don't know the theory behind it but I think that most people will perceive a better experience if the objects move slowly. If there is a big gap (maybe Java doing a very big garbage collection) it could become a problem (and you could check for the gap becoming too large if you want) but mostly there will be just a few skipped rendered frames (unless your frame rate is too high) and it will still feel smooth to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Game logic should not be tied to framerate.

Some games don't use 60 ticks per second, some (like Minecraft) run at 20 ticks per second. That would effectively lock the game at 20 fps.

Even if all games ran at 60 ticks a second, what if someone has a 144 Hz monitor? He'd be stuck playing at 60 fps.

If you render the game more frequently than the ticks, you can still run animations and other stuff in the render logic, while the game logic is stopped for however long it has to be, making the game fluid even if its tick frequence is slower than your monitor's refresh rate.

Comment: So apparently I don't understand the "update" concept. In Minecraft, what update do? Turning the player view is on the render method?

Comment: A tick is whenever game logic is calculated. Taking Minecraft as an example, it can be anything from a door opening to a block breaking to a redstone circuit updating. The player view is detached from ticks in order to be more fluid.

Answer (score 1):

What does tick and render method do?

1. Tick (or update, but I like tick more) method just update game objects’ states. For example, it updates player coordinate, processes input, check current state (menu, game, pause)and update it and so on.
2. Render method just draw it into the screen. It like a painter that draw something based on feelings. But in our case he based on some variables and other information.

How does they do their work?

1. Tick method updates specific times per second (for example, 20, 60 and so on). I call that number UPS (stands for updates per second). Let’s consider player movement. His speed is 20 pixels per second. So if we want to move our player with this speed we need to know UPS. For example, UPS is 20. So our player will move 20 pixels per tick. And that’s wrong. If it is then with our 20 ticks, for 1 second our player will move 20*20 pixels (400 pixels per second). So speed of our player will be 20 * (1 / UPS) per tick. We can change our UPS and number of pixels player move per tick will be changed too. But he will be still move 20 pixels per second. To make it clear assume our UPS is 1 it means one tick per second. Then speed will be 20 * (1 / 1) = 20 pixels per tick (in one second is one tick) = 30 pixels per second. The same as we want.
2. Render just draws what we update. It can do it with the same rate as we update also I it can do it faster. But it doesn’t matter, because we will see only what we update. UPS can be 1 but FPS is 160. You will see everything move every second. But it doesn’t mean that we render 1 time per second it mean that for one second we render the same picture. After 1 second we update our game and we will see another picture.

And answer your question you can use tick() and render() together.

Answer (score 0):

All it takes for it to be worth rendering faster than the game state can be updated is the player to be moving, causing stationary objects to change their angle of the screen as the player walks past them or turns.

The fluidity of this motion is particularly critical for VR software:

> Studies have shown that in practice, any VR setup that generates frame rates below 90 frames per second (FPS) is likely to induce disorientation, nausea, and other negative user effects. [[source](https://help.irisvr.com/hc/en-us/articles/215884547-The-Importance-of-Frame-Rates)]

---

We can also linearly interpolate the motion of moving objects between game updates to provide more continuous movement:

`position_now = position_last_game_loop + (velocity_last_game_loop * time_since_last_game_loop)`

which, whilst not perfect, means a moving object 'snaps' from the approximate position to the game loop position, rather than from the last game loop position to the new one. (This works best if objects can't accelerate or break incredibly fast). (This could similarly use acceleration data.)